# исключение из списка несуществующий в системе emoji

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

у меня есть массив emoji... но я хочу исключить те emoji которых нет в текущей системе. на текущий момент я получаю черные дефолтные смайлы вместо некоторых emoji.
Заменять emoji svg или png изобраджениями исключено так как они повышают размер исходной страницы... поэтому хочу просто убрать те некоторые emoji которые не поддерживаются.

Comment: нет в текущей системе... какие системы?

Comment: Все системы ...

Comment: я имею введу про что речь про windows и тгд?

Comment: Android, iOS, Linux, Windows, Mac OS

Comment: а по коду в браузере черные от остальных отилчаются как то?

Comment: нет юникод не отличается. но на одном браузере это цветная emoji а на другом черная

Comment: единственное что я сумел узнать что в  console.log(window.navigator.appVersion) есть инфа про операционную систему и основоваясь на этом можно разделить на подмоссивы и сфармулировать исходный массив основоваясь на системе не думаю что это лутшее решение но на данный момент только это